# Как объединить сети с различной маршрутизацией в одну сеть в Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: маршрутизация, static, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer, ospf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы объединить автономные сети с различными протоколами маршрутизации в одну сеть, то есть, чтобы все роутеры из различных сетей пинговались друг с другом.
Настроены 4 автономные сети, настроенные по разным протоколам маршрутизации: Static, BGP, OSPF, RIP. Все роутеры внутри каждой автономной сети пингуются друг с другом. Нужно объединить сети Static, OSPF, RIP с помощью сети BGP.

Конфигурация объединённой сети приведена на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При объединении в одну сеть для каждого роутера из сети BGP были добавлены дополнительные смежные сети:

- для роутера BGP1 добавлена сеть 172.16.5.0/30;
- для роутера BGP2 добавлена сеть 150.150.5.0/30;
- для роутера BGP3 добавлена сеть 10.10.14.0/30.

На данном этапе роутеры из разных сетей не видят друг друга.
Собственно, что нужно сделать дальше? Нужно ли, например, для роутера BGP1 настроить дополнительно маршрутизацию по протоколу RIP?

Вот файл проекта - [скачать](https://yadi.sk/d/20d5P7X0-YD17Q).

Comment: Объединение сетей с разными протоколами маршрутизации возможно только на базе статических маршрутов. Соответственно на каждом пограничном маршрутизаторе необходимо прописать статические маршруты во все неизвестные ему на текущий момент подсети. И убедиться, что эти маршруты либо присутствуют, либо переданы соотв. протоколом, на не-магистральные маршрутизаторы сетей и на клиентские узлы.

Comment: Маршрутизаторов в сети BGP, как я понимаю, может быть очень много. Неужели на каждом нужно прописывать статические маршруты? Зачем тогда BGP? Либо вы ошибаетесь, либо я вас не так понял.

Comment: Если пограничный маршрутизатор передаст известные ему маршруты на другие (внутренние) маршрутизаторы и узлы - конечно, нет... а вот убедиться, что он это сделает - нужно.

Comment: Вы правы. После добавления статического маршрута на роутер BGP1 в сеть 172.16.0.0 пакеты стали приходить в эту сеть извне. Но вот незадача, не получается из сети RIP выйти в сети STATIC и OSPF. В сеть BGP начал выходить после того, как в роутере BGP добавил сеть 34.0.0.0 в RIP. Как сделать, чтобы в сети 150.150.0.0 и 10.10.0.0 тоже можно было выйти из сети RIP?

Comment: Если в какую-то подсеть маршрута нет - смотрите, кто должен был бы передать этот маршрут. Смотрите там. Если там он есть - разбирайтесь, почему не передаётся. Если нет - думайте, откуда и по какому протоколу он должен был бы его получить. Так и проходите по всей инфраструктуре от каждой подсети до всех остальных подсетей.

Comment: Например, для *Как сделать, чтобы в сети 150.150.0.0 и 10.10.0.0 тоже можно было выйти из сети RIP?* - начинаете с сети RIP и смотрите, передаётся ли маршрут роутерам сети BGP. Если нет - делаете так, чтобы передавался. Далее ... ну 150.150 - статика, там роуты пишутся руками (?). А 10.10 - смотрите, попадает ли маршрут из роутеров сети BGP в сеть OSPF, если нет - налаживайте.

Comment: Не получается пробросить маршрут из сети RIP наружу до сетей 150.150.0.0 и 10.10.0.0. Если ввести на роутере, например RIP1, команду sh ip route, то отобразятся только все пути в сети 172.16.0.0. Как добавить в таблицу маршрут до сети 150.150.0.0?

Comment: Получается, из сети Static (150.150.0.0) пакеты доходят в сеть RIP (172.16.0.0) нормально, а вот обратно отклика нет, так как в сети RIP неизвестен маршрут до 150.150.0.0. Я пробовал прописать на роутере BGP1 сеть RIP 150.150.0.0, но видимо, раз сам роутер к этой сети непосредственно не подсоединён, то и путь в таблице не прописывается.

Comment: Из сети Static (150.150.0.0) пробросить маршруты наружу легко, достаточно добавить статический маршрут 0.0.0.0/0 via 150.150.5.1. Как это сделать в RIP, ума не приложу.

Comment: Теоретически - `redistribute static`.

Comment: Это на каком роутере нужно прописать?

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается, нужно было просто-напросто маршруты по умолчанию в каждой сети прописать.